# Pentagon with UISLiders as circumradii

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I want to draw a `pentagon` in iOS with `UISliders` as the `circumradii` (a set of five `UISliders` going in different directions and originating from the center of a pentagon). Currently I have rotated five `UISliders` using a common `anchorPoint` (`:setAnchorPoint`), but they dont seem to originate from a common point. 
How can I go about this? Do I need to start working on a custom control? What more from `Quartz2D` can I use?
Some specific indicators would be useful (please don't just say "Use `Quartz2D`")

Here is what I have achieved [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/8UBv7ZQ)

And here is what I want to achieve [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/R6Nh08u)

Comment: If you are not interested to use Quartz2D then start work using CoreGraphics framework.

Comment: Add a screen shot of what you have and what you want, and the code you're currently using.

Comment: Its not that I dont want to use Quartz2D, I just wanted to know if its the best approach. I am tight on schedule and so cannot afford to try my hand at different options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined the various sliders as an IBOutletCollection, so I can access them as an array in the controller. Then I run the following code in `viewWillAppear:`

```
CGPoint viewCenter = self.view.center;

for (NSInteger i = 0, count = self.sliders.count; i < count; ++i) {
    UISlider *slider = self.sliders[i];

    CGFloat angle = 2.0f * M_PI / count;

    CALayer *layer = slider.layer;
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
    layer.position = viewCenter;
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(i * angle - M_PI_2, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: Circumradii sliders]

Is this that you want?

Comment: Thats exactly what I intended to do. Did you make any changes in the xib? I am unable to reproduce the results here.

Comment: No, just put the sliders anywhere in the XIB, they'll be repositioned anyway. Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: Voila! You solved it!! Thanks. I needed the anchorPoint bit. When added, even my older code ran fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would try just to turn the sliders. The following code should help:

```
firstSlider.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(firstSlider.transform,72.0/180*M_PI);
secondSlider.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(secondSlider.transform,144.0/180*M_PI);
//and so on
```

The `72.0/180*M_PI` is transformation of degrees to radians.

Hope it helps.

P.S. don't have a mac nearby to check if it works

Comment: The sliders seem to turn on their central point. So I set one end of a slider as the anchor point for all and in xib, laid them over each other (all five sliders at one place, same coordinates). I got the same results as in the image I have attached in my question.